# Contacting server in JS client side form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form. I am already doing a client side HTML.

```
    <form id='myForm' onsubmit='return myFormValidation()'>
       ...
    </form>
```

Now, in myFormValidation function, after making sure the client side is OK, before really submitting the form, I want to do also a server side form validation.
I am using JQuery. So,I changed my function to something like this:

```
function myFormValidation(){
  //first, client side validation
  ...
  //then, server side validation
  $.post(url_of_server_side, $("#myform").serialize(), function(json) {
    data = JSON.parse(json);
    if(!data.ok)
    {
       $("#msg").text("some error");  
    }
    else
    {
       $("#myForm").submit();//Oops!
    }
    });
    return false;
}
```

But the "submit" function of form behaves like a recursive function and tries to validate the form again!
Should I disable the validation function before calling submit? Or, I guess, there is a better way for my problem (which is slightly or even totally different than this)?

Comment: I found an indirect "solution": Instead of normal post, I do synchronous post. This way, I can get rid of submit call !

Answer (score 1):

If you need server side validation you should extend your "Save" enpoint to support correct response status codes and do not use separate "Validation" url. Use single url with different response types:

- 200 (Success) - data was saved successfully
- 400 (Bad request) - input data was incorrect. As response message you can include "validation result" message which you will display to user.

So your code can looks like

```
$.post(url_of_server_side, $("#myform").serialize())
  .done(function() {
    //show some success confirmation or redirect to main page
  }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    $("#msg").text(error.message);  
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. This is quiet helpful. But I abstracted my example. In server-side validation, I also generate some extra information (like messages) to show to user. with this 400 status, I cannot pass this info to client.

Comment: You can use any JSON in response as you want.  And include other properties you need to show. Not only "message". Some more complex object.

Comment: @thanx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, if all data is OK, the server-side script to perform the action that you want, e.g. saving to database. That way, you will not need a second post of the form in case everything is correct.
If something is wrong, then obviously, the checks must take place the second time as well.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more? Do you suggest I don't do server-side validation?

Comment: What you are writting is if(error) then show error else resubmit();
If everything is correct, why not saving the data in one step and just showing OK to the user

Comment: You are right. This is true if I use synchronous ajax post (the comment I wrote under my question) whereas as I wrote in my question, the post is async and the thing you are saying is not possible.

Comment: I see, do not use synchronous calls, your users will kill you :). After clicking that submit button, disable it at first, so the user cannot resubmit it again. That solves the asynchronous problem, if I understand correctly the issue.